# Anaconda é um tipo de plataforma para Python?

Tags: python

Anaconda é um tipo de plataforma/solução Python como a da ActiveState ou é uma distribuição? Estou utilizando o sistema operacional Windows e gostaria de saber se Anaconda é uma boa escolha para data mining!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você esteja se referindo a [este](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) produto, caso não seja desconsidere a resposta.

Na verdade o Anaconda é uma plataforma open source para cientistas de dados, ele une o R (linguagem de programação para estatística) e o Python, além de módulos do Scala.

Sugiro dar uma olhada na documentação no link que eu botei ali, mas acredito que não é o que você procura.